# Why driver.get() method is not recognized?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I have setup selenium in Intellij Idea. But when tried to create a simple instance it doesn't recognize "get" method.
This is what I have done up to now.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();   
driver.get("http://www.google.com");  // get is in red and doesn't allow to import any package
Thread.sleep(5000); // Sleep also has same problem
```

How can I fix this?
I have added jar files. I'm using java webdriver

I have added jars inside the zip of selenium downloaded file
I did imports as they were suggested. I deleted the project. So, I don't have the code and imports now.
Even the thread cant identify its methods. For and example `Thread.` doesn't suggest methods available.
declaring the driver didn't cause any trouble. But `driver.`doesn't suggest any method including 'get'

[image: Image of the code]

Comment: Lets improve your question so that more folks could help you. Which jars did you add? Show us your imports. Which problems does your Thread.sleep have? What happens if you type "driver." after "WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); " line? Does code assistant show you some available methods to select?

Comment: May I add an image?

Comment: Let's try and edit later if it won't help.

Comment: Ok give me several minutes

Comment: @AlexeyR., I have added more info in the question please check

Comment: Could this be an error of the way I created the project?

Comment: can you share the stacktrace

Comment: @joe did you configure JDK? If even Thread does not provide methods for selection, then I assume you haven't configured jdk properly.

Comment: Both projects have same JDK

Comment: Go to "File/Project Structure/SDKs". Can you screen-shot the window and paste to your question?

Comment: It seems that Selenium jars or packages are not configured correctly. Are you doing this stuffs in eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer for the problem. All I had to do is include the code inside a main method as follows.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("URL");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add all the dependent jars to your project. You are getting the RED color in the method calls because the corresponding classes are not present in the project and JDK is not able to resolve the path.

Go to Module settings --> add the selenium jar --> apply

Answer (score 0):

You need to use URL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) which means full https (or http) address to make it work. Try:

`import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
 public class SeleniumDemo {
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

 driver.get("http://www.google.com");
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 }`

Comment: I havent use the same link here and it has http and properly declared

Comment: I do not understand what you did. Can you paste in the whole stacktrace from IntelliJ? And your full .java file (probably you messed up imports)

Comment: All im getting is Cannot resolve symbol 'get'

Comment: Probably you didn't get imports on the top, and didn't properly created Java Class. Try edited code?

Comment: I have imported all those

Answer (score 0):

Import the **Remote Webdriver** and run the code. This will work.

```
RemoteWebDriver driver;
```

or else try this below code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "give the chrome driver path here");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
//To maximize the window
driver.manage().window().maximize();
//Need to load the url
driver.get("google.com");
```

[image: methods not suggested issue]

Comment: I have set chromedriver path as a environment variable and it works in another project properly

Comment: Check the current project chrome driver path and update. Else update the new chrome driver.

Comment: Itried to set the path manually as you have told in second code segment. But it doesn't recognize "setProperty"  Says "Cannot resolve symbol setProperty"

Comment: Can u pls share the code which u have created now so that i can help u

Comment: I have added the new code on above the existing code.

Comment: Did it too. Doesn't work. And it doesnt address my real problem

Comment: Use forward slash and not backward slash. C://chromedriver_win32. Try this.

Comment: Just did it. But no

Comment: Added an image please check

Comment: Use Chromedriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: Also give C://chromedriver_win32.exe. add .exe in the prefix and do with the above change. This will work

Comment: You are suggesting for driver path. But it's not my main concern. I want to fix the problem of not recognizing methods

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to check your driver path is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

eclipse--window-preference--java-editor--advance--select all java proposals

it worked for me

Comment: Please also add why this should solve the problem, adding concrete steps is usually considered not a complete answer.